# Representing conformers using SMILES and Graph representations

Tags: cheminformatics, conformers

I was wondering if either of SMILES or graph representations (in their vanilla form) can distinguish between two conformers of the same molecule.

1. Can this be enhanced by adding additional metadata on Graph nodes?
   what info are necessary then?
2. Can this be enhanced for SMILES representations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the SMILES strings as defined by [Daylight](https://daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html), you can expect these representations tell about the molecular constitution *plus* information about ($E$/$Z$)- and CIP's $(R)$/$(S)$-configuration. But nothing about the conformation like the boat / twist form of cyclohexane which generally is dynamic, or a faithful preservation of information like *s-cis* to describe the conformation of butadiene favorable for the Diels-Alder cycloaddition reaction.

Further, *I speculate* SMILES strings are not a faithful representation of locked conformations as in the axial $P/M$ configuration of 2,2',6,6'-substituted 1,1'-biphenyls. However, perhaps someone else may clarify this point.